# Mysql on ubuntu and Jupyter on host machine

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I am trying to connect MySQL or MongoDB installed on a guest machine Ubuntu (VM) with Jupyter notebook installed in my machine (host). I installed `mysql.connector` in Jupyter, I am having trouble getting a connection.

```
dab = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user=" ", 
  passwd=" ")
```

Should I add more info above, or I have to install mysql and mongodb on my host machine?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to connect to a mysql server, that server must exist. So yes, you need to install a mysql server on your local machine if that's where you want to store the data.

Comment: Actually, it's already installed in my guest machine (ubuntu) and that's where i want to store the data. But how to connect it with jupyter running on host machine (macos).

Comment: There is a host parameter in the connect method...

Comment: It doesn't work for my problem. Maybe something matters in the network of the vm itself ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but without some kind of an error message, we can only guess.